# Getting attachment from outlook using Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have a created folder in my outlook named "Reports". This folder contains emails with one attachment in each email. I would like to use ACCESS VBA to save the attachments from the "Reports" folder in Outlook to a local drive in my computer. here is the code I have so far, but gives me errors. Please help:

```
Sub GetAttachments()

Dim ns As NameSpace
Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Dim Item As Object
Dim Atmt As Attachment
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer


Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set Inbox = ns.Folders.Item("Reports") // I get an error in this line says an object could not be found 


i = 0

If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
   MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", vbInformation, _
        "Nothing Found"
   Exit Sub
End If


For Each Item In Inbox.Items
   For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
     FileName = "C:\Automation\" & Atmt.FileName

     Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName   // here is another error says method is not found
     i = i + 1
   Next Atmt
Next Item
```

Answer (score 2):

Is your Reports folder within your Inbox folder? You may need to do something like this:

```
Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set RptFolder = Inbox.Folders("Reports")
```

Your syntax for saving attachments looks correct (apart from your comments not being correct for VBA). You could print out the Filename that you are creating to see if it's a valid name. And I assume that you have created the Automation folder that you mention.

**Update:** 
Try declaring your Atmt as an Outlook.Attachment. There is such a thing as an Access.Attachment which does not have a SaveAsFile method, and it's probably picking that one up first. If you include the library name, you should get the one you need.

**Update 2:**
To get to your Reports folder, one way is to get the Inbox folder as you are currently doing, then get its parent, then get the Reports folder under that.

```
Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set Mailbox = Inbox.Parent
Set RptFolder = Mailbox.Folders("Reports")
```

Another way would be to scan the items under "ns" to find the one that starts with "Mailbox", then get the Reports folder under that. It seems a little more cumbersome than getting the parent of the inbox. That also seems cumbersome, but I couldn't find a way to get to the Mailbox folder directly.

Comment: Hi Todd, Thanks for your answer. Actually, the "Reports" folder is not within my Inbox folder. It is directly under Mailbox.

Comment: And for saving the attachment, when I write atmt.  the property "SaveAsFile" does not show from the list. do I need to add any specific reference for that? Thanks,

Comment: I will research it tomorrow and find a solution for you. One thing you could try to do is to list the values in ns.Folders.Items to see what you're actually working with. As for the attachments SaveAsFile, I assume you already have the Outlook reference added to have gotten this far. I would look in the Object Browser to verify that it's supposed to be there, and also check that you're getting the correct Attachment object type that you need. I don't have Office on this machine, otherwise I would be more specific. What version of Office are you using?

Comment: Ok thanks Todd. I am working with MS office 2007. The attachment is a pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
           For Each Item In Inbox.Items
             For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
               FileName = "C:\Automation\" & Atmt.FileName

               Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName   // here is another error says method is not found
               i = i + 1
            Next Atmt
```

With.....

```
          For Each Item In Inbox.Items
            For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
              FileName = "C:\Automation\" & Atmt.FileName

              Attachments.SaveAsFile FileName   // here is another error says method is not found
              i = i + 1
           Next Atmt
```

Outlook does not have a problem with atmt in the reference however, MS Access does.  This should fix your problem.

Davis Rogers

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Dim Atmt As Attachment
```

with

```
Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
```

It'll make Access find the correct Class for atmt.